# RewriteMap to choose an ID from the end of url and if it matches replace the url end with another url end

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I thought I'd write here if someone could help me out here, I've been trying to get this thing to work for a few days but I can't really seem to understand how should I configure RewriteMap to get what I need.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap myredirects txt:/var/www/redirects.txt
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id\=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/story/(.*)$ ${myredirects:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L,R=301]
```

Something like this I have configured but I am clueless how off I am from getting the configuration to work. As of now it doesn't work for sure.

What I would need is I have a webpage that is about to get its content deleted and I would need to redirect it to another page instead of a 404. 
I have a site IE: book.com/story/[dynamic-url-from-page]?id=654672

I want to configure it so when the end of the url matches the one in RewriteMap text then it will Rewrite to book.com/firm?f=1233456

My redirects.txt is set up pretty much like this 
/story/dynamicurlexample?id=59368 /firm?f=1154657

Is it possible to do what I need with this module? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'll try to progress on my own as much as I can but help would be great.

The main problem is that RewriteMap has the issue of recognizing "? question marks" before the "id=" therefore I can't simply Rewrite site to site, I need a workaround. It can redirect to a site with a questionmark but not from one.

Thanks for reading!
DeltX5

Comment: `RewriteCond ${myredirects:%{REQUEST_URI}} .+

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*id=${myredirects:}

RewriteRule ^ ${myredirects:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L,R=301]`

I tried a different approach this time, hoping to get this thing to work.